# How to prevent coercion to list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove all `NA` values from two columns in a matrix and make sure that neither column has a value that the other doesn't. 
code:

```
data <- dget(file)

dependent <- data[,"chroma"]
independent <- data[,"mass..Pantheria."]

names(independent) <- names(dependent) <- rownames(data)

for (name in rownames(data)) {

    if(is.na(dependent[name])) {
      independent$name <- NULL
      dependent$name <- NULL
  }

    if(is.na(independent[name])) {
      independent$name <- NULL
      dependent$name <- NULL
  }
}
print(dput(independent))
print(dput(dependent))
```

I am brand new to R and am trying to perform this task with a for loop. However, when I delete a section by assigning `NULL` I receive the following warning:

```
1: In independent$Aeretes_melanopterus <- NULL : Coercing LHS to a list
2: In dependent$name <- NULL : Coercing LHS to a list
```

No elements are deleted and `independent` and `dependent` retain all their original rows.

file (input):

```
structure(list(chroma = c(7.443501276, 10.96156313, 13.2987235, 
17.58110922, 13.4991105), mass..Pantheria. = c(NA, 126.57, NA, 
160.42, 250.57)), .Names = c("chroma", "mass..Pantheria."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Aeretes_melanopterus", 
"Ammospermophilus_harrisii", "Ammospermophilus_insularis", "Ammospermophilus_nelsoni", 
"Atlantoxerus_getulus"))
                              chroma mass..Pantheria.
Aeretes_melanopterus        7.443501               NA
Ammospermophilus_harrisii  10.961563           126.57
Ammospermophilus_insularis 13.298723               NA
Ammospermophilus_nelsoni   17.581109           160.42
Atlantoxerus_getulus       13.499111           250.57
```

desired output:

```
structure(list(chroma = c(10.96156313, 17.58110922, 13.4991105
), mass..Pantheria. = c(126.57, 160.42, 250.57)), .Names = c("chroma", 
"mass..Pantheria."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Ammospermophilus_harrisii", 
"Ammospermophilus_nelsoni", "Atlantoxerus_getulus"))
                            chroma mass..Pantheria.
Ammospermophilus_harrisii 10.96156           126.57
Ammospermophilus_nelsoni  17.58111           160.42
Atlantoxerus_getulus      13.49911           250.57
structure(c(126.57, 160.42, 250.57), .Names = c("Ammospermophilus_harrisii", 
"Ammospermophilus_nelsoni", "Atlantoxerus_getulus"))
Ammospermophilus_harrisii  Ammospermophilus_nelsoni      Atlantoxerus_getulus 
                   126.57                    160.42                    250.57 
structure(c(10.96156313, 17.58110922, 13.4991105), .Names = c("Ammospermophilus_harrisii", 
"Ammospermophilus_nelsoni", "Atlantoxerus_getulus"))
Ammospermophilus_harrisii  Ammospermophilus_nelsoni      Atlantoxerus_getulus 
                 10.96156                  17.58111                  13.49911
```

Comment: `x$name` uses the name "name" not the string stored in the variable `name`. Instead use `x[[name]]`

Comment: This actually gives me another error: Error in dependent[[name]] <- NULL : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace

Comment: Ok, hmm, I don't use those packages, but I guess it's something to do with how you're supposed to interact with objects of that class. Btw, you might improve your odds of someone figuring it out by making a minimal reproducible example; guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Comment: Looks like you have a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`.

Comment: Overall, I think this would be much clearer if you shared a reproducible example. There's probably a better way, but without seeing either sample input or desired output, it's hard to know. Please use Frank's link as a guide and share some data reprodicibly, for example using `dput()`.

Comment: @Gregor I included some sample data as well as my desired output. Let me know if there's anything else I should include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to omit rows from your data where `chroma` or `mass..Pantheria` are `NA`. Here's a quick way to do it:

```
data = data[!is.na(data$chroma) & !is.na(data$mass..Pantheria.), ]
```

I'm not sure why you are breaking `independent` and `dependent` out separately, but *after* filtering out bad observations is a good time to do it.

Since those are your only two columns, this is equivalent to omitting rows from your data frame that have any `NA` values, so you can use a shortcut like this:

```
data = na.omit(data)
```

---

If you want to keep a "pristine" copy of your raw data, simply change the name of the result:

```
data_no_na = na.omit(data)
# or
data = data[!is.na(data$chroma) & !is.na(data$mass..Pantheria.), ]
```

---

As to what's wrong with your code, `$` is used for extracting columns from a data frame, but you're trying to use it for a named vector (since you've already extracted the columns), which doesn't work. Even then, `$` only works with a literal string, you can't use it with a variable. For data frames, you need to use brackets to extract columns stored in variables. For example, the built-in `mtcars` data has a column called `"mpg"`:

```
# these work:
mtcars$mpg
mtcars[, "mpg"]

my_col = "mpg"
mtcars[, my_col]
mtcars$my_col ## does not work, need to use brackets!
```

You can never use `$` with row names in a data frame, only column names.